# How not to use escape character in java

Tags: java, escaping, character

I have to use \" in a string but apparently, I cant. 
To be more specific I need to do something like:
Let's say the string is something like:

`I like cookie's "%s"`

`str = str.replace('"', '\"');`

But I need the string to look like this after the replace :

`I Like cookie's \"%s\"`

Is anyone willing to help?

Comment: `str = str.replace("\"", "\\\"");` You have to escape the quotes and the backslash as well

Comment: The first \ will escape the second one, then the third one will escape the `"` and the result will be `\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that " and \ are both special characters. In order to use them as literals in strings, you need to escape them. So the correct way would be:

```
str = str.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

In this context the strings are broken down as such, with spaces around the characters or clarity:

```
" \" " This is an escaped quote
" \\ " This is an escaped backslash
```

Thus if you want to represent a backslash followed by a quote, you can see that is breaks down as:

```
" \\ \" " Quotes around the whole literal, an escaped backslash, an escaped quote
```

Comment: Your escaped examples broken down are using forward slashes and not the back slashes you meant to use. Same as the special character in the beginning. \ is the special character not /.